# Glue not able to recognize Delta Lake Python Library

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I am trying to use Delta Lake Python Library in my Glue job. However, my Glue job is not able to recognize it and I get the error "NameError: name 'DeltaTable' is not defined". Per Glue-DeltaLake documentation , I added the paramter --datalake-formats = delta and also updated the required spark configuration

```
.config("spark.sql.extensions","io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog","org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
```

My code fails at below line

```
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark,self.dest_path_sdad)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the import statement

```
from delta.tables import *
```

Answer (score 0):

These configuration properties configure Glue with the Delta Lake file format, so you can write `spark.read.format("delta").load(...)` or `df.write.format("delta").save(...)`. But they doesn't provide the Python API that is available as the [delta-spark](https://pypi.org/project/delta-spark/) package.  It could be made available to Glue by using the `--additional-python-modules` option ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html)).

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Actually now Glue supports passing the data lake format as a parameter (--datalake-formats = delta) in which case it includes the Python API and required jars without having to explicitly add them. The issue was I did not have below import statement. Adding this fixed it.

from delta.tables import *